# How to adjust the height of Ionic 4 IonContent at runtime

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have an `Ionic 4 / Angular` application where I have a component shown in a Modal (which probably makes no difference to this question)

When I build (`Cordova`) and run on a Windows tablet, there is no auto app sizing when the soft keyboard is displayed (I have accepted this for now).

Anytime I have an input that will display this keyboard, I need to manually adjust the contents do I can have the input showing above the keyboard.

I am trying to adjust the height of an `IonContent` when my input received focus.

eg I have the following...

```
    public async onTextFocus(ev: any): Promise<void> {
        try {
          let i = 0;
          let el = await this.content.getScrollElement();
          let style = el.style;
          el.setAttribute('height', '50%');

          style = el.style;
          let j = 0;

        } catch (error) {
          this.logger.error(`MyComponent.onTextFocus: ${error}`);
        }
      }
```

So I am attempting to set the content to `50%`, but when I do the above nothing happens. Also, when I reexamine the style after calling  the `el.setAttribute('height', '50%');` the height is still not set (it is just an empty string)

Using devtool, I have tried adjusting the height of everything I can find. The only thing that works is if I set it on the parent component (but have no idea how to do this at runtime).

How can I resize the height (so I can then set back in the onBlur), so I can then see my input element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error, found at least one way of doing this..

There may be a better way, but one way that does work is simply..

```
let el = await this.content.getScrollElement();
el.style['height'] = '50%';      
this.content.scrollToBottom();
```

Seems to work fine